# Why can't I change the offset of a DateTime in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to change the offset of a `DateTime`, like so:

```
> n = Time.now
=> 2016-11-15 16:42:04 +0000
> n.change(year: 1980)
=> 1980-11-15 16:42:04 +0000
> n.change(offset: "-05:00")
=> 2016-11-15 16:42:04 +0000
```

As you can see, it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to change the offset in this manor. The only things that `change` is allowed to change are `:year`, `:month`, `:day`, `:hour`, `:min`, `:sec`.

You can see this in the current code at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb#L96-L101.

I think you will want to use `DateTime` instead.

Comment: ahh i see. it actually is allowed in DateTime, which I now see i wasn't using https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb#L49-L60

Answer (score 2):

Try to use DateTime class instead of Time

```
> dt = DateTime.now
=> Tue, 15 Nov 2016 19:53:02 +0300
> dt.change(offset: "-05:00")
=> Tue, 15 Nov 2016 19:53:02 -0500
```